# Dapper and Entity framework for modeling classes

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, dapper

I want to start using Dapper because I think it's easier to use with Stored procedures than to map every stored procedure with Entity Framework to replace CRUD operations in general.

I would like to know how can I create the POCO classes with dapper, and if it is not possible, could I create the model from the Database using Entity framework and then use the classes created with dapper?

Thanks!

Comment: This has already been answered earlier: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11056141/how-to-generate-model-from-database-using-dapper

Comment: Thank you, i had seen that, however my question is more specific and 3 years have passed since the previous question was asked. i just want to have some updated info, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of projects where I have used dapper alongside Entity Framework / nHibernate.

There is a distinction between the POCO classes created for Dapper and the domain entities used by code first Entity Framework and you should create both.

Stored procedures will work with a shaped view of the data and do not have the responsibility of representing the entire domain.

Following single responsiblity practises the POCO classes you use should only contain those properties used by the stored procedures to are interfacing with.

If you are not using Entity Framework for data access and want to replace it completely with Dapper and stored procedures then you are failing to realise any of the benefits of an ORM and should simply hand craft the schema and the POCO classes it uses.

You can generate POCOS from  a schema and tools exist to do this, given the overhead of creating your own classes which can be better tailored to the application layer I woudl suggest there would be no benefit.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm using stored procedures because the DBA insists on using them even for CRUD operations. now for what i've understood, i could create the DB model with Entity Framework, then create the additional models I'd need for the Stored Procedures, and at the end use Dapper to handle all the Database-App transactions, right?

Comment: The point of EF is that is provides automatically synchronised data access between the domain and the schema. Using Dapper for data access would make EF almost entirely redundant - what benefits do you expect to realise using it over a hand crafted schema and stored procedures? You would be making your development process more complicated without realising any benefits. 

DBA's are reticent start using ORMS as their best practises demand the use of SPs. I've experienced this friction myself. You need to convince your DBA on the use case for ORMS or I'd suggest you avoid using them.