# Can Dapper create a model class from DB tables?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, dapper

I'm looking over some alternatives to EF, and Dapper seems like a pretty good option. But I do have one question. I understand that Dapper, being a Micro ORM doesn't rely on or use a class of models, like EF creates. That being said, what if I still *want* a buncha models that mirror my db tables?  How would I generate them and keep them up to date?  Or, at least, some of my tables?

This is from the Dapper GutHub page:

```
public class Dog
{
    public int? Age { get; set; }
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public float? Weight { get; set; }

    public int IgnoredProperty { get { return 1; } }
}            

var guid = Guid.NewGuid();
var dog = connection.Query<Dog>("select Age = @Age, Id = @Id", new { Age = (int?)null, Id = guid });

Assert.Equal(1,dog.Count());
Assert.Null(dog.First().Age);
Assert.Equal(guid, dog.First().Id);
```

So in this exampe, was the `Dog` class manually created?

Comment: What do you mean by "manually created"?  Typed by a programmer?  Constructor called?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11056141/how-to-generate-model-from-database-using-dapper

Comment: Good question.  I meant typed by a programmer, but what I really should have said was, "Was the creation of the Dog class somehow automated?  And if so, how?"

Comment: @maccettura - yup, that's it.  Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate model from database using Dapper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11056141/how-to-generate-model-from-database-using-dapper)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You will need to create `Dog` class by yourself. Dapper is just a wrapper around ADO.NET.

If you want to save time, you could just generate POCO from EF Code first from Database or [Entity Framework Power Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=EntityFrameworkTeam.EntityFrameworkPowerToolsBeta4), and use it in Dapper.

Answer (score 3):

Why dont you utilize EF code first migration to maintain/sync your domain models and database. Dapper will work with these entities that generated by EF code first migration